# Skip duplicate records when appending using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, sql, file-geodatabase, append

The objects I want to check have unique ID's (edit: these ID's are different from OID's and will remain the same when copied). I'm appending one file geodatabase to another, and I want to make sure I'm skipping any duplicate objects. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: OID's can be the same in two separate GDB's so you will need a new approach to determine duplicates other than OID

Comment: I have a field with unique record ID's in addition to the OID's generated by arc. The record ID's remain the same even when an object is duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with a little more time. This can be done using the delete identical tool. Use the recordID field as the input field.

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox